# Patching a file (in this case dwm) and failed hunks

Tags: diff, patch, dwm

I'm trying to add the `transparency` patch to `dwm`. I downloaded the `.diff` file and in my dwm directory ran this:

```
max@linux-vwzy:~/misc/dwm/dwm-5.9> patch < dwm-transparency.diff 
patching file config.def.h
patching file dwm.c
Hunk #1 FAILED at 58.
Hunk #5 succeeded at 306 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #6 succeeded at 847 (offset 27 lines).
Hunk #7 succeeded at 882 (offset 27 lines).
Hunk #8 FAILED at 1125.
Hunk #9 succeeded at 1558 with fuzz 1 (offset 2 lines).
2 out of 9 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file dwm.c.rej
```

I've patched `dwm` before to add a couple other patches. Is it possible that they are conflicting? Or is this another error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The patch is failing because the other patches that you have previously applied have shifted the code around sufficiently to defeat patch's attempts to apply the change, even with an offset (as can be seen in those hunks that did succeed).

If you open `dwm.c.rej` you will see the failed hunks, then it is just a matter of hand patching them in to `dwm.c`.

For each failed hunk, search in `dwm.c` for the original code (the lines that begin with a `-` in `dwm.c.rej`) and replace them with the patched code (those lines beginning with a `+`). If dwm recompiles without error, you have successfully patched in transparency.

Comment: Thanks jason, I'll give this a try in a couple minutes when I get my font right